# Cypress has started throwing 417 Expectation Failed error on all POST and PUT XMLHttpRequest

Tags: http, cypress

All POST and PUT XMLHttpRequest made into Cypress have recently started throwing 417 Expectation Failed. However all these work on the web application when I navigate through it manually.

All my code used to work well in past without any issue.

I read about this error over internet and I'm not sure if this issue exists on the application under test, or on some firewall policy or there is some setting in Cypress which can fix it.

```
Cypress.Commands.add("Post_Client", () => {
  cy.fixture(Cypress.env("ClientInputFile")).then(clientoBJ => {
    cy.fixture(clientoBJ.imagePath, "binary").then(imageBin => {
      Cypress.Blob.binaryStringToBlob(imageBin, clientoBJ.imageType).then(
        blob => {
          const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
          const data = new FormData();
          data.set(clientoBJ.nameatr, clientoBJ.nameVal);
          data.set(clientoBJ.imageatr, blob);
          xhr.open(
            "POST",
            Cypress.env("APIBaseURL") + Cypress.env("ClientPostURL"),
            false
          );
          xhr.setRequestHeader("accept", "application/json");
          xhr.setRequestHeader("access-token", accesstoken);
          xhr.setRequestHeader("client", client);
          xhr.setRequestHeader("expiry", expiry);
          xhr.setRequestHeader("token-type", tokentype);
          xhr.setRequestHeader("uid", uid);
          xhr.onload = function() {
            if (this.status === 201) {
              cy.writeFile(
                Cypress.env("ClientOutputFile"),
                JSON.parse(this.responseText)
              );
              cy.readFile(Cypress.env("IDStore")).then(obj => {
                obj.clientID = JSON.parse(this.responseText).client.id;
                cy.writeFile(Cypress.env("IDStore"), obj);
              });
            }
          };
          xhr.send(data);
        }
      );
    });
  });
});
```

And then it is called in a Test

```
  it.only("CLIENT API POST TEST", () => {
    cy.Post_Client();
  });
```

Comment: Can you try the same request through Postman/ any ReST client and see if you could reproduce? We will come to know if it is Application issue or the Cypress issue.

Comment: These requests work fine from POSTMAN and App UI. Problem is surfaced when I do it from Cypress. This is very confusing because this works for some APIs and not for others.

Answer (score 0):

This stands fixed now.There were two problems causing this and both were at the application layer.

Problem# 1 - Somehow we chose 417 as the error code for any unhandled events.
Fix - We are now using 422 error code for unprocessable entities

Problem# 2 - A formData append method has three params -(name, value, filename) where filename is optional. It is made mandatory in the application code recently.
fix -

```
data.set(
            clientoBJ.imageatr,
            blob,
            clientoBJ.imagePath.substring(
              clientoBJ.imagePath.lastIndexOf("//") + 2
            )
          );
```